# How to determine what driver stops shutdown

Tags: windows-10, freeze, shutdown

Installed Windows 10 on a new computer but every time the computer shuts down (also while installing Win10) the laptop freezes up with a black screen. How can I determine what driver and/or device is responsible for this freeze?

NB: Only longpress on the power button is able to get out of the freeze and afterwards Windows restarts without a notification about the hard reset.

The laptop is an 6700K Intel Skylake CPU, 980M NVidia GPU and Samsung 951 pcie NVMe SSD in a Clevo body.

I did wait several minutes (is reproducible every time), no harddisk activity, no fan but laptop turns warm and drains battery.

Also tried doing a clean boot and even a boot to safe mode. show the same behaviour. In safe mode the screen does not freeze to black but vthe rebooting animation just halts and the computer freezes.

Comment: Trial and Error.  I normally use Autoruns to boot into a minimum configuration then proceed to determine which driver is misbehaving by enabling each driver one by one.

Comment: Can you please give us some details about the computer? How long have you waited? Is there any hard drive activity? Any warnings or errors in the Event Viewer?

Comment: on win7 i've used a command to show what is preventing sleep. Try that one. `powercfg -requests` may help, or  perhaps may not apply at all.. See if it is preventing sleep as well, I guess it would be.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/331796 this method may help you find the offending program or driver.

Comment: Since there is no notification about hard restart, it could be a video driver misbehaving.

Comment: @Moab: since the problem persists in safe mode I don't think it is the video driver.

Comment: I would try a different video card then.